# Symfony4: render cannot pass parameters

Tags: twig, symfony4

After updating from Symfony 2.X to Symfony 4.4 and verifying the operation, I found that Twig does not recognize modal.
Since it does not recognize modal, it will be displayed even when the code that is not displayed in modal in the if statement is displayed in modal.
When I tried "if modal is empty", the code in the if statement was displayed, so it seems that the modal is not passed.
The code that passes the modal has changed with the Symfony update. This may have an effect.
Do you have any idea?

Old_code

```
    <div id="imageDialog" title="Image management">
        {{ render(controller("AppBundle:Shop/Image:manager", {"modal": true})) }}
    </div>
```

Changed_code

```
    <div id="imageDialog" title="Image management">
        {{ render(controller("AppBundle\\Controller\\Shop\\ImageController::managerAction", {"modal": true})) }}
    </div>
```

Code in question

```
    <div class="tabpanel selected" id="imageFolder" >
        <div class="tabcontent">
            <div class="operations">
                {% if not modal %}
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <form method="post" action="{{ path('app_shop_image_delete') }}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="methods" value="delete">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token("authenticate") }}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="[]">
                            <button type="submit" class="delete btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ImageController

```php
     *
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/manager")
     *
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Shop/Image/manager.html.twig")
     */
    public function managerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $routeParams = $request->get('_route_params');
        $uploadUrl = $this->generateUrl("app_shop_image_save");
        return array(
            'modal' => isset($routeParams["modal"]) ? $routeParams["modal"] : false,
            'form'  => $this->createUploadForm($uploadUrl)->createView(),
        );
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear. You want the code into `{% if not modal %}` to be displayed only when you pass `{"modal": false}` and it's displayed in both cases `{"modal": true}` and `{"modal": false}` ?

Comment: @jona303 "Code in question" is a partial excerpt. I want the submit button to be displayed when the "Code in question" page is accessed from a route that is not the root containing ```modal: true```. However, now the buttons are displayed on all routes.

Comment: Did you debug in the profiler to see what's passed as `modal` value to your render ? Your code seems ok so I guess there's something wrong with your requests params. Also there's a method to get queryParameters : `$request->query->get('modal')` that's null if not exists.

Comment: @jona303 I put in the code I received and tried ```dump($routeParams)```, but it was null. It seems that I can't pass the parameters in render.

Comment: @jona303 Addendum: When I dumped ```$request```, there was "modal: true" in attributes, and ```$routeParams = $request->attributes->get('modal')``` was done, and ```dump($routeParams)``` When I did, "true" was returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine with the following method.
I couldn't get `$routeParams["modal"]`, but please let me know if there is a way to get it.

```php
    public function managerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $routeParams = $request->query->get('modal');
        $uploadUrl = $this->generateUrl("app_hq_image_save");
        return array(
            'modal' => isset($routeParams) ? $routeParams : false,
            'form'  => $this->createUploadForm($uploadUrl)->createView(),
        );
    }
```

```
     <div id="imageDialog" title="Image management">
         {{ render(controller("AppBundle\\Controller\\Shop\\ImageController::managerAction", {}, {"modal": true})) }}
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function managerAction(Request $request)
{
    $isModal = $request->query->get('modal') != null ? $request->query->get('modal') : false;
    $uploadUrl = $this->generateUrl("app_hq_image_save");
    return array(
        'modal' => $isModal,
        'form'  => $this->createUploadForm($uploadUrl)->createView(),
    );
}
```

But I wonder if you shouldn't make modal as a real route param with a default value `false`.
https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/routing.html#optional-parameters